# Struts 2 - How to populate a combobox considering another combobox choice

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I would like to know what I am doing wrong or if I am on the wrong track, trying something impossible.

In my jsp I have two s:select and some textfields. Considering the choice of the first one I have to go search some informations on my database. What I am trying to do is everytime I choose some option in my first combobox I call a method im my action, this method get the informations I need from my mysql and populate my list(this list is the options of the second combobox), but of course this is not working because I am not reloading my jsp, the problem is that I cannot reload because I don't want to lose the information I have in the textfields.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Use javascript. And show you code.

Comment: Don't reload it if you can't and you don't loose the information valuable to you.

Answer (score -1):

you'd better use Ajax to load the data for your first ComboBox or some other fields data (page without re-loading,thus)